# Setting custom font in UITextView with attributed string

Tags: ios

I have a `UITextView` which contains an attributed string configured through storyboard. Now i want a custom font to be applied. I am doing it through code

```
textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kCustomFont size:textView.font.pointSize];
```

The problem is fonts get changed losing all the attributes. How do i fix it?

(Working on iOS 5 and above)

Comment: fonts would be a problem in many ways. For instance, Are you seeing the default font after setting the font for your textView?? If yes, then the prob with font only. You need to install that font in your mac and check the exact font name in your fontbook. Font wont have the same name after it installed. So check it out in that way too.

Comment: You should post the value of kCustomFont here.

Answer (score 0):

You should change it via NSMutableAttributedString's attributes.

I.e. use something like:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:textView.text];
NSDictionary *attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[mutableSrting addAttributes:attrs range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableString length])];
textView.attributedText = mutableString;
[mutableString release];
```

Comment: Which one, and on which line?

Comment: @orak you should post the exception. However, it's most likely you haven't got the right font name.

Comment: textView.text = mutableString;
at this line exception fire   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7068cc'

Comment: shouldn't it be `textview.attributedText = mutableString` ?

Comment: Uh. Looks like you are right. I wrote code without checking it.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your kCustomFont? If the FontName is wrong, even a single Character, the standard SystemFont will be used.